# Reactjs/Graphql: Stop graphql query from executing when page is loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

After some debugging, I found out that when the page loads React is executing the following query:

```
export default graphql(Query, { 
    options: (props) => ({ 
        variables: { 
            start: props.start,
            end: props.end
        } 
    })         
)(Comp);
```

The error from the server is 'Bad Request' which seems to be because start and end are empty and they are assigned as Float! Of course, those variables are going to be empty; the user has not entered values.

When I input values in the UI and click on submit it works fine.  I just need help figuring out how to prevent this query from executing when the page loads. And only execute when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post more code, specifically the constructor, componentWillMount and componentDidMount

Comment: have you tried setting the `skip` prop to true? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#props

Answer (score 2):

Just provide a `skip` function to `qraphql` hoc:

```
export default graphql(Query, {
  skip: ({ start, end }) => (!start || !end),
  options: ({ start, end }) => ({
    variables: { start, end }
  })
})(Comp);
```

Comment: No more error on page loading, however, now, when the submit button is pressed the app crash.

Comment: This feels like a totally separate issue.. I would suggest you to create a new question and provide the full component code

Comment: When the submit button is pressed the console is showing an empty array just like after the page load.  So, it looks like skip is being implemented even when the submit button is pressed and the query is not being executed. With this error message: `Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined`.

Comment: And again, this is a totally separate issue. Can't tell nothing without seeing the code

Comment: Seems like there are some issues with skip, https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/289. Thanks for the help though.